# how to add timestamp to stdout and stderr from a crontab job?

Tags: shell-script, cron, timestamps

I want putting timestamp traces into two different files when I call to the script from a cron task. One file is for stdout `script.log` and another for stderr `script.err`

With this cron line I get timestamp over `script.log` file, but don't work with `script.err`

```
*/1 * * * * ((/home/user/script.sh) | ts "\%H:\%M:\%.S ->") 2>>/home/user/script.err >> /home/user/script.log
```

How I can add timestamp into `script.err` too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to redirect stdout of ts first, and then redirect stderr of the pipeline to stdout and pipe to another `ts`::

```
*/1 * * * * (/home/user/script.sh | ts "\%H:\%M:\%.S ->" >> /home/user/script.log) 2>&1 | ts "\%H:\%M:\%.S ->" >> /home/user/script.err
```

(Though this way, and stderr output from the first `ts` will also be logged be the second `ts`.)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @muru